# Stubbing a Property get using Rhino Mocks

Tags: c#, properties, rhino-mocks, stub

Using RhinoMocks, I am trying to Stub the getter value of a property. The property is defined as part of a Interface with only getter access.

However I get the error "Invalid call, the last call has been used or no call has been made (make sure that you are calling a virtual (C#) / Overridable (VB) method)." I understand this may mean that the property I am stubbing is not virtual; However it is part of the Interface and I am not sure if that is the reason why I get this error..

Below is the code skeleton. If I uncomment the line which says "stubRepository.Stub(x => x.StoreDeviceID).PropertyBehavior();", then I get a new error "Property must be read/write". I searched on SO and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301116/rhino-mocks-error-invalid-call-the-last-call-has-been-used-or-no-call-has-bee) page. But the proposed solution doesn't help me. Any thoughts?

```
public interface IStore {
        string StoreDeviceID {get;}
        //other methods
    }

    public static class Store {
        private IStore Repository;

        public void SetRepository(IStore rep){
            Repository = rep;
        }

        public StoredeviceID {
            get{
                return Repository.StoreDeviceID;
            }
        }

        //other methods
    }

    public class TestClass {
        [Test]
        public void TestDeviceID() {
            var stubRepository =
                MockRepository.GenerateStub<IStore>();
            Store.SetRepository(stubRepository);

            //stubRepository.Stub(x => x.StoreDeviceID).PropertyBehavior();
            SetupResult.For(stubRepository.StoreDeviceID).Return("test");

            Assert.AreSame(Store.StoreDeviceID, "test");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Since this is a read only property, you need to say:

```
stubRepository.Stub(x => x.StoreDeviceID).Return("test");
```

Normally with stubs, properties are used like normal C# properties.  So for non-readonly properties, you would say: `stubRepository.someProperty = "test";`

Also note that if you wanted to set up a **method** to behave a certain way, regardless of whether it's a mock or a stub, you would always say:

```
stubRepository.Stub(x => x.someMethod()).Return("foo");
```

Remember, stubs are there to supply your unit tests with their needed dependencies, but are *not* there to run verifications on; that's what mocks are for.

Use a stub when you want to supply a dependency that behaves a certain way.  Use a Mock when you want to verify that a certain dependency has been interacted with correctly.

From the (outstanding) [Rhino Wiki](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+3.5.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1):

> A mock is an object that we can set expectations on, and which will
>   verify that the expected actions have indeed occurred. A stub is an
>   object that you use in order to pass to the code under test. You can
>   setup expectations on it, so it would act in certain ways, but those
>   expectations will never be verified. A stub's properties will
>   automatically behave like normal properties, and you can't set
>   expectations on them.
>
> If you want to verify the behavior of the code under test, you will
>   use a mock with the appropriate expectation, and verify that. If you
>   want just to pass a value that may need to act in a certain way, but
>   isn't the focus of this test, you will use a stub.
>
> IMPORTANT: A stub will never cause a test to fail.

Comment: @ Adam, Since the Property is readonly, I cannot set on it. However, the code snippet you provided to Stub the property works perfectly. Silly me, I tried all other options except that :)

Comment: StoreDeviceID does not have a setter, so your first statement `stubRepository.StoreDeviceID = "test";` will not work.

Comment: Ahh - sorry.  I will update my answer - glad you got it working though.

Comment: In newer version of Rhino Mocks the difference between mock and stub has been blurred yes? (unless you're using strickmock and such)

Comment: When I try this, I get the error: You are trying to set an expectation on a property that was defined to use PropertyBehavior.
Instead of writing code such as this: mockObject.Stub(x => x.SomeProperty).Return(42);
You can use the property directly to achieve the same result: mockObject.SomeProperty = 42;

Answer (score 4):

You can do the following with a stub:

```
stubRepository.Stub(x => x.StoreDeviceID).Return("test");
```

This will cause it to return "test" for any call to StoreDeviceID's getter.